# Hibernate not working on MacBook Pro with Debian

Tags: debian, suspend, hibernate

I've installed Debian testing/stretch on a brand new Macbook Pro 13" (early 2015), but hibernation isn't working properly.

When I try to hibernate, it *appears* to work (the screen shuts off after a few seconds), but the system seems to never fully power off (this is demonstrated by the fact that the cooling fan eventuall comes on if I put the laptop in my backpack, and also by the fact that to reboot I first have to do a forced shutdown by holding in the power button for a few seconds). And then when I try to reboot, it never wakes up from hibernation, either.

I've been googing for a solution, but can't find anyone else with the exact same symptoms, and can't find anything at all about hibernation on this specific hardware.

Comment: The description of your MBP problem reminds me of my own trouble.
Try to troubleshoot with this particular document. Doing step by step debugging has worked with my MBP 11,1 running linux. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt

Answer (score 0):

You may have a driver loaded that prevents correct hibernation. Does `lsmod` show that e. g. `bcm5974` is loaded? If so, `modprobe -r bcm5974`, then try hibernating again.

Obviously, if this helps, you'll need to `modprobe` the module after resume. This can be easily automated.

Another thing to try would be to install `uswsusp`. It has config options for different shutdown methods. So:

1. `apt-get install uswsusp`
2. edit /etc/uswsusp.conf and try different options for `shutdown method`. Try `shutdown method = platform` and `shutdown method = shutdown`.
3. run `s2disk` as root to hibernate to disk.

Comment: It looks like removing the 'brcmfmac` module allows the hibernation to succeed. Although automating the process is proving not to be intuitive.

Comment: @Flimzy what DE/WM are you using?

Comment: KDE. Although I don't mind editing conf files directly... but installing pm-utils and creating a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d/* had no effect.

Comment: It seems KDE [prefers systemd hooks](http://chakraos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=78715#p78715), so try this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Hooks_in_.2Fusr.2Flib.2Fsystemd.2Fsystem-sleep

Here's an example systemd hook script that you can edit to fit your needs: https://gist.github.com/shawnbon206/3a451a7612084d9392cd

Comment: But basically you can simply run a shell script as simple as  `rmmod brcmfmac && s2disk && modprobe brcmfmac` through a desktop shortcut. Unfortunately, I do not have access to KDE or even systemd at this time, so I'm not in the best position to help with these. If it's OK for you to create a desktop/panel hibernation shortcut, I would recommend installing and using the `hibernate` package. It has a ton of ready-made hooks, including for loading and unloading modules. I could help with that.